# Function analog for .map for a collection that changes during processing?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I have the problem of trying to 'process' (as in, 'run a function on') elements in a collection, like you would do with `map` or `foreach`.  The problem is that the collection can change during processing - the processing function can add new elements that need to be processed.  In imperative form, I'd keep a stack of these elements and push-to/pop-from the stack until it was empty.  I am currently doing this with a mutable list but the format of the code that results is poor.  Is there a standard immutable functional idiom for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like OP has a function that can either give an answer or require additional work to be done. The easiest way I can think of to solve this is to have the function generating the answer recurse so it never returns something requiring additional work.

Comment: I'd figured out the answer.  It involved a difference list.  Thanks for setting me straight.